# Using user created variables to create a random number Android

Tags: java, android, xml

So I am trying to create an android app that will generate a random number based on 2 numbers submitted by the end user. I have the following code which works until you click on the generate button:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText nu1;
EditText nu2;
TextView number;
Button button1;
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){
            int min = Integer.parseInt(nu1.getText().toString());
            int max = Integer.parseInt(nu2.getText().toString());
            number.setText("Random Number: " + randomGenerator(min, max));
        }
    });


    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

public static int randomGenerator(int min, int max) {


    Random rand = new Random();

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((min - max) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/value"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/value"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nu2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/no2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nu1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/no1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/but" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.bruinstech.numbergen"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:name="com.bruinstech.numbergen.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

And finally the Error that occurs when the button is clicked :

```
07-02 13:09:31.137: D/AndroidRuntime(1933): Shutting down VM
07-02 13:09:31.137: W/dalvikvm(1933): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d6bb20)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): Process: com.bruinstech.numbergen, PID: 1933
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.bruinstech.numbergen.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-02 13:09:31.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1933):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Debugger points to this line

```
int min = Integer.parseInt(nu1.getText().toString());
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided

Comment: Which variable is null on that line? Use a debugger, or at least some print statements, to figure that out.

Comment: Don't use print statements... use a debugger, period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `EditText` are `null`, you need to do this before your button click code

```
nu1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nu1);

nu2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nu2);
```

Your `onCreate()` would change to :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nu1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nu1);
        nu2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nu2);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                int min = Integer.parseInt(nu1.getText().toString());
                int max = Integer.parseInt(nu2.getText().toString());
                number.setText("Random Number: " + randomGenerator(min, max));
            }
        });

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
   }
```

Comment: So am I right in thinking that this will go before the onClick but after the onCreate?  Because when I do this, it just crashes on load

Comment: @bruins1993 Yes your `onCreate()` would look like the updated code.